# Itinerary if only one party shows up

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, group-travel

I know that if one books multi-leg itinerary and one does not present oneself to one of the legs, the remainder of the flight may (will?) be forfeit.

I am curious to know what would happen if I were to book an itinerary for several people and one of the passengers fails to check in for one of the flights. Would the whole itinerary be in jeopardy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**.  The tickets for the no-show passengers will be cancelled, but the rest of your party will be unaffected.

More specifically, the T&C for airlines (as a random example, here's [Singapore Airlines](https://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/global_footer/conditions-carriage/)) differentiate between a Ticket and the Passengers on that ticket.  All the rules about showing up on time etc apply to *individual* Passengers, eg. Article 7:

> If the Passenger fails to arrive in time at Carrier's check-in location or boarding gate [...] Carrier may cancel the space reserved for him.

Note the singular: *the* Passenger/him, not all Passenger*s*/them.

Comment: Would you mind provindong a.reference?

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I believe you know what you're talking about, but I would really love to be able to have the confirmation from an actual ticket fine print or something.